# Is multi dimensional array what I am looking for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

It will seems basic stuff for most of you guys but I'm stuck on this problem:

So I have 3 categories of fields like this:

```
-Category 1 = [field1, field2, field3.. etc]
-Category 2 = [field1, field2, field3.. etc]
-Category 3 = [field1, field2, field3.. etc]
```

And on top of that, I have others elements which has all of those categories but not all fields like this:

```
 Element 1 = Category 1[field3, field2], Category2[Field4], Category3[field1, field5, field2]
```

How am I supposed to organize those data in javascript (I am using Jquery if it can help)?

Comment: use multi-dimensional array for storing the **categories**, use string concatenation for building up the value for **elements**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many programming languages support arrays with named indexes.

Arrays with named indexes are called associative arrays (or hashes).

JavaScript does **NOT** support arrays with named indexes.

In JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes.

You may use objects instead:

```
{
    "Element1": {
        "Category1": [
            "field3",
            "field2"
        ],
        "Category2": [
            "field4"
        ],
        "Category3": [
            "field1",
            "field5",
            "field2"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is you are a complete beginner to JavaScript and it's data types.

[Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) might help too in getting the basics of javascript.

Comment: You may dive into Douglas Crockford's material to get a deeper understanding of Javascript later on. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do with the data but one way could be:

```
var category1 = ['field1', 'field2', ... ];

var element1 = { 
  category1: ['field3', 'field2'],
  ...
}
```